# How to delete the last entered value in java?

Tags: java

Ok so I have created a simulation of a machine scanning an item. Where Machine is a class and Item is a separate class. I can currently set an item to a price and then have the machine scan it and add up the total price, and number of items scanned. What would be the easiest way to delete the last scanned item? Would it need to involve an arraylist or something like that? Btw I am very new to java so any help would be great! Here is my code so far:

```
public class Machine
{
    // Both balance and count feilds below.
    private double balance;
    private int count;

    // This is the constructor method, it sets both the balance and count to 0.
    public Machine ()
    {
        balance = 0;
        count = 0;
    }

    // This simply returns the value of balance.
    public double getBalance ()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    // This simply returns the value of count.
    public int getItemCount ()
    {
        return count;
    }


    /* This simulates an item being scanned and is added to total item count,
     * as well as adding its price to the total balance.
     */
    public double scanItem (Item item)
    {
        balance = balance + item.price;
        count = count + 1;
        return item.price;
    }


    // This prints the receipt, showing the balance and total item count
    public void printReciept()
    {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("##########################");
        System.out.println("     Purchase summary     ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("   Total balance: $" + balance + "  "); 
        System.out.println("Total item count: " + count + " items");
        System.out.println(" " );
        System.out.println("  Thank you for shopping  ");
        System.out.println("         with us!         ");
        System.out.println("##########################");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("           --             ");
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

        balance = 0;
        count = 0;
    }    

    // This method clears the balance and count
    public void clearAll()
    {
        balance = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

and my Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public double price;

    public Item(double paramPrice)
    {
        price = paramPrice;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a list and manage it according top your needs... add, deleteat(...) etc

Answer (score 4):

Just to give you some sample code (npinti gave the right answer, whereby I would not remove the balance calculation, performance is better when you calculate it - which will only really matter if you have a lot of items in your basket).

```
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

public double scanItem (Item item) {
    balance = balance + item.price;
    items.add(item);
    return item.getPrice();
}

public int getItemCount () {
    return items.size();
}

public void removeLastItem() {
  if (items.size() == 0) {
      return;
  }

  Item item = items.remove(items.size() - 1);
  balance -= item.price;
}

public void clearAll() {
    balance = 0.0;
    items.clear();
}
```

Just some information regarding your `Item` code. You made the price attribute `public` and provide a getter. In general, you should change the visibility of the attribute to `private` and just use the getter method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to use some sort of collection. The easiest would be to use an `ArrayList<Item>` to keep track of what is being added.

Using ArrayLists the elements are added at the end of the list, thus, if you want to remove the last added item, you can simply remove the tail of the list.

Through an ArrayList you can also make the following modifications to your code:

1. Balance could be removed from a global field. When you ask for the balance, you would simply iterate and compute the total.
2. Count could also be removed, and you would return the size of the array list.

In case you do not make such changes, do not forget to deduct 1 from Count should you remove elements from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stack which is LIFO ordered (last in first out) and all you would need is `lastItem = stack.pop()` and then subtract the value of that item from the balance.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the last item added (“scanned”), you need to remember that item. Or at least remember its price.

If the requirement is strictly “be able to delete last item added”, then add an instance variable to the Machine class, called something like `lastItemScanned`. Add a line to your `scanItem` method:

```
this.lastItemScanned = item;
```

In your method to remove last item, first check to see if `lastItemScanned` is null. If not, decrement your count, reduce your total, and set `lastItemScanned` to null.

More practical would probably be remembering all the items added. For that you need a data structure known as a collection. There are many kinds of collections each with advantages and trade-offs. A `List` is indeed probably appropriate as the interface, with `ArrayList` probably being a good choice as concrete implementation. The other Answer that just appeared may show that. You can also find many examples on Stack Overflow.

Using and storing the passed Item object only makes sense if the object is not changing (“mutating”) in any significant way during the entire time the Machine object needs it.

By the way, your class has serious problems in terms of not being thread-safe. But that can be ignored for an introductory programming exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Jiri is correct. There are some advantages with a collection (like being able to print the items on the receipt), but for this particular requirement it is not necessary.

```
public class Machine
{
    // Both balance and count feilds below.
    private double balance;
    private int count;
    private Item lastItem;

    // This is the constructor method, it sets both the balance and count to 0.
    public Machine ()
    {
        balance = 0;
        count = 0;
        lastItem = null;
    }

    // getBalance and getItemCount as before

    /* This simulates an item being scanned and is added to total item count,
     * as well as adding its price to the total balance.
     */
    public double scanItem (Item item)
    {
        balance = balance + item.price;
        count = count + 1;
        lastItem = item;
        return item.price;
    }

    /** This deletes the last value entered */
    public boolean deleteLastItem() {
        if (lastItem == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            balance = balance - lastItem.price;
            count = count - 1;
            lastItem = null;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // This prints the receipt, showing the balance and total item count
    public void printReciept()
    {
        // as before

        balance = 0;
        count = 0;
        lastItem = null;
    }    

    // This method clears the balance and count
    public void clearAll()
    {
        balance = 0;
        count = 0;
        lastItem = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `.remove(index)` method of ArrayList to remove last element. Just replace `index` variable with `size of list - 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever need to delete the last item (and never two last items etc.), it is enough to store just the last price (or last `Item`).

If you choose this approach, make sure to add some defenses against deleting the last item twice (e.g. check for `null` before deleting the last item, then set the last item to `null` after deleting).

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of stack. As stack is LIFO ordered (last in first out),you can pop out the last item using `stack.pop()` and subtract it from 'balance'.

See here for the detail about stack:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html